# Incorrect translation of 'shipping' at woocommerce checkout page after WC update 3.4*

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

After updating Woocommerce to to 3.4* the translation of the shipping label at the checkout page doesen't work. The translation files are correctly configured but the english translation "Shipping" is showing where the Swedish translation "Frakt" where previously shown. (before updating Woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common bug likely caused by the WC update. To solve the issue the best solution currently seems to be use the filter "woocommerce_shipping_package_name"

```
function custom_shipping_package_name( $name ) {
  return 'Frakt';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 'custom_shipping_package_name' );
```